# Openconnect - name or service not known when using sudo

Tags: 16.04, networking, vpn, openconnect

I've been using `openconnect` with no problems at all, but since yesterday when I try to connect to the `VPN` using `sudo` it fails:

```
lmoreyra@arbanlmoreyra1:~$ sudo openconnect vpn-am2.infor.com
[sudo] password for lmoreyra: 
POST https://vpn-am2.infor.com/
getaddrinfo failed for host '': Name or service not known
Failed to open HTTPS connection to vpn-am2.infor.com
Failed to obtain WebVPN cookie
```

I know that there is a way to avoid using `sudo` (in which case it the VPN partially works) but I rather avoid it.

Any ideas what is the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you manage to fix this?

Comment: @Kosta Hi, just answered my own question, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find a solution, but found a workaround.

Installed

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openconnect-gnome
```

And then connected through the Ubuntu's NetworkManager.
[image]

Comment: not worked for me

Comment: this is not workaround for your question . it's only a GUI application for create Cisco VPN . your problem is Not related to it .